# Delete file after <p:fileDownload> is finished or cancelled

Tags: jsf, events, jsf-2, primefaces, download

I create a temporary file on my webserver. This file is downloaded via the [`<p:fileDownload>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileDownload.jsf). This works fine. However, when the download is finished or aborted, then I need to delete this temporary file. I don't know how I can check this event.

There's a `PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop)` available in JavaScript, but as I observed and understood, the `stop` event is triggered once server is ready serving the download and the download window opens, so it's not useful to me.

How can I delete the file once the `<p:fileDownload>` is finished or cancelled?

Comment: When exactly do you create the temp file? Before or during click of `<p:fileDownload>`? If during click, then you could just stream it directly to response instead of first to disk file system and then re-opening another stream to it for the response.

Comment: First, thanks for editing the first post :) . I add the file before on the server. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the actionListener attribute of the p:commandButton that contains your p:fileDownload. Like so:

```
<p:commandButton ... actionListener="#{myBean.deleteFile()}>  
    <p:fileDownload ... />  
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: This solution i've tried before. The problem is that the actionlistener executes before the download is ready and the file cant delete.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but one option that I could think of is you can use FileDownload monitor and inside the stop function use **`<p:remoteCommand>`** to trigger file deletion on server.